# how to select value in mySql

Tags: mysql

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `My_PRO`(in employeId int)
    BEGIN
    declare  allocatedvalue1 int default 0; 
    declare  allocatedvalue2 int default 0; 
    declare  appliedvalue1 int default 0; 
    declare  appliedvalue2 int default 0; 

set allocatedvalue1=(
    SELECT sum(day) FROM Parabola.leave_allocated where employee_id=741   and
     leave_type_id=42 and year='2016') ;

     set appliedvalue1=(
     select IFNULL(FORMAT(sum(hours/8),1),0)from leave_applied where 
     employee_id=741 and leave_type_id in(42) and status in (1,2,5)and
    (start_date>='2016-01-01'
    and end_date<='2016-12-31' ));

    set allocatedvalue2=(

    select sum(day) from compensatory_leave where
     employee_id=741 and status in(2,3));    

    set appliedvalue2=(
    select sum(day) from compensatory_leave where 
    employee_id=741);       
    END
```

This is my Procedure  i want to display value like this

```
**label             applied**

 FirstLeave       allocatedvalue1/appliedvalue1
SecondLeave        allocatedvalue2/ appliedvalue2
```

Please suggest my how  to write inside procdure so that i can get value like given structure i am able to get value in all allocatedvalue1,appliedvalue1 ... but i am unable to select value so that i can get desire value.

Comment: You can always jam your data in a report table and do a select from it at the end. That said, mysql is an RDBMS. Why are you trying to make a report engine out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
select 'FirstLeave' as FirstLeave,allocatedvalue1/appliedvalue1 as fvalue1

union all

select  'SecondLeave' as   SecondLeave,      allocatedvalue2/ appliedvalue2 as fvalue2
```